# pandas binning a list based on qcut of another list

Tags: python, pandas, binning

say I have a list:

```
a = [3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 8]
```

and a sub list of a:

```
b = [5, 2, 6, 8]
```

I'd like to obtain bins by `pd.qcut(a,2)` and count number of values in each bin for list b. That is

```
In[84]: pd.qcut(a,2)
Out[84]: 
Categorical: 
[[1, 3], (3, 8], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], (3, 8], [1, 3], (3, 8], (3, 8], (3, 8]]
Levels (2): Index(['[1, 3]', '(3, 8]'], dtype=object)
```

Now I know the bins are: [1,3] and (3,8], and I'd like to know how many values in each bin for list "b". I can do this by hand when the number of bins is small, but what's the best approach when the number of bins is large?

Answer (score 5):

You can use retbins paramether to get bins back from qcut:

```
>>> q, bins = pd.qcut(a, 2, retbins=True)
```

Then use `pd.cut` to get `b` indices with respect to bins:

```
>>> b = np.array(b)
>>> hist = pd.cut(b, bins, right=True).labels
>>> hist[b==bins[0]] = 0
>>> hist
array([1, 0, 1, 1])
```

Note that you have to treat corner case, `bins[0]`, separately, as it is not included by cut in leftmost bin.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in earlier answer: You can get the bin boundaries from `qcut` using the `retbins` parameter, as in the following:

```
q, bins = pd.qcut(a, 2, retbins=True)
```

Then you can use `cut` to put values from another list into those "bins."  For example:

```
myList = np.random.random(100)
# Define bin bounds that cover the range returned by random()
bins = [0, .1, .9, 1] 
# Now we can get the "bin number" of each value in myList:
binNum = pd.cut(myList, bins, labels=False, include_lowest=True)
# And then we can count the number of values in each bin number:
np.bincount(binNum)
```

*Be sure that your bin bounds cover the entire range of values that appear in your second list.*  To ensure this you might pad your bin boundaries with the max and min value.  E.g.,

```
cutBins = [float('-inf')] + bins.tolist() + [float('inf')]
```